# Allure support for running threaded tests

Tags: multithreading, pytest, allure

Simple question - is `allure` supported with parallel `pytest` variants, like [pytest-parallel](https://github.com/browsertron/pytest-parallel) and [pytest-concurrent](https://github.com/reverbc/pytest-concurrent)?

Both of these `pytest` variants allow individual tests to be run in in a thread-pool. That part is working fine. The problem I'm having is getting `allure` to work with them.

When I just use the bog-standard `pytest` all is fine.

```
pytest -lvs  --alluredir=allure simpletest.py
...

dir /x allure
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 780F-2C58

 Directory of C:\Users\XXX\allure

04/03/2020  14:15    <DIR>                       .
04/03/2020  14:15    <DIR>                       ..
04/03/2020  14:15                 6 15B0C0~1.ATT 15b0c095-9809-4054-aad4-5f92123af984-attachment.attach
04/03/2020  14:15             2,382 2A5A56~1.JSO 2a5a5697-ea48-4b6c-a697-1e858d1a06ab-result.json
04/03/2020  14:15             2,035 487A7C~1.JSO 487a7cfd-69ba-4b8a-ae02-95dd092abdca-result.json
04/03/2020  14:15                 6 4B3F99~1.ATT 4b3f9954-21e3-4a11-8897-23617e67678b-attachment.attach
04/03/2020  14:15                 6 DA6010~1.ATT da601030-9330-4e12-a123-f67be3f445e5-attachment.attach
               5 File(s)          4,435 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  11,812,552,704 bytes free
```

When I run the same test with either [pytest-parallel](https://github.com/browsertron/pytest-parallel) and [pytest-concurrent](https://github.com/reverbc/pytest-concurrent) I see the allure output directory created, but nothing gets written to it.

```
pytest -lvs  --alluredir=allure simpletest.py
...

dir allure
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 780F-2C58

 Directory of C:\Users\XXX\allure

04/03/2020  14:18    <DIR>          .
04/03/2020  14:18    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  11,822,096,384 bytes free
```

I don't see anything on the [allure-pytest](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python) site or the [allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) site that mentions threading.

Comment: Log start and end of two tests to file, with just a sleep in between. If they overlap, they are being executed concurrently.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I know that the tests are being executed concurrently from the raw pytest output -- I added logging to output the thread id so I know they are being executed in separate threads. My problem is getting the allure data output.